# PostgreSQL SELECT WHERE IN - with value are special character

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a issue when using SELECT search query with condition such as below:

> select * from t_user where mailAddress in ('**mail1'@gmail.com**,
>   **'mail2&@gmail.com**, **&&&mail3''@gmail.com**')

Email in **IN()** is dynamic.

How I can use above query without change email address.

P/S : I use Postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php + may be some query builder?